# .htaccess rewrite arbitrary query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying the following rewrites

`1. 
http://domain.cm/app/user/view?group=3&userid=34
to http://domain.cm/app/user/view/group/3/userid/34`

`2. http://domain.com/app/class/edit?classid=13
to
http://domain.com/app/class/edit/classid/13`

Is this can be achieved with one rule? I have lots of such URLs that needs to be rewritten and creating one rule for each looks very redundant.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need seperate rules (at least for the examples you provided).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, though it may be a little too eager to match *anything*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:([^/]+)/|)(?:([^/]+)/?|)$ /app/$1/$2?$3=$4&$5=$6 [L,QSA]
```

That makes is so if you request something like:

```
http://domain.com/app/class/edit/classid/13
```

you get served the content at

```
/app/class/edit?classid=13
```

It can handle as many as 6 path nodes, so:

```
http://domain.com/app/a/1/b/2/c/3
```

will get routed to:

```
/app/a/1?b=2&c=3
```

For even more, just add another `(?:([^/]+)/|)(?:([^/]+)/?|)` before the `$` and a `&$7=$8` at the end of the rule's target.

Comment: Thanks, however I am trying to rewrite the URL only. My app is using URLs with query string and now I need to change how they appear on the browser address bar.